# Powers of Rotation matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the rotation matrix
 $A=   \begin{bmatrix} \cos \ x & \sin \ x \\       
          -\sin \ x  & \cos \ x \end{bmatrix}  $.

Then $A^2,A^4 A^6$ etc. gives identity.  Why?
Do this have any connection with de moivre's theorem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The statement is not true. Recapitulate the term "Rotation".

Comment: Take for example rotation $A$ by $ \pi/2$. What is rotation $A^2$ ?

Answer (score 4):

$A^2$ is not the identity, $A^2$ is

$$A^2=\begin{bmatrix}\cos^2 x-\sin^2 x & 2\sin x \cos x\\ -2\sin x \cos x & cos^2 x-\sin^2x\end{bmatrix}$$  This simplifies to $$A^2=\begin{bmatrix}\cos(2x)&\sin(2x)\\-\sin(2x)&\cos(2x)\end{bmatrix}$$

which is the matrix of rotation by $2x$ (because rotating twice by an angle of $x$ is the same as rotating once by an angle of $2x$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $A^2$ gives rotation by $2x$. If $nx$ is a multiple of $2\pi$ you’ll get identity for $A^n$, not otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a $2\times2$ irrep of $SO(2)$, $R(\varphi)$, you can show
$$R^{n}(\varphi)=R(n\varphi)$$
If $\varphi\in2\pi\mathbb{Z}$, then you get identity