# Orbit of a vector under the action of a $2\times 2$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, geometry

Consider the following matrix $A=\pmatrix{0 &1\\
-1&\frac{1}{3}}$ and put  $e_1:=(1,0)^t$. How can I find the elements of the orbit $A^ne_1$, for $n\in\mathbb N$?

It seems to me that $A$ has infinite order in $SL_2(\mathbb R)$ and moreover I don't see any closed formula for the powers of $A$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First let's note that characteristic polynomial of $A$ is $P_{A}(t) = t^{2}-\frac{1}{3}t+1$, which is irreducible over $\mathbb{R}[t]$ since it's root are $\frac{1}{6}(1 \pm i\sqrt35)$; In particular, it's irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}[t]$.

Since the minimal polynomial of $A$,denoted with $m_{A}$ divide the characteristic polynomial but the second one it's irreducible,

We can now assert that the minimal polynomial of $A$ and the characteristic polynomial coincide.

If $A$ would have finite order,for the [Hamilton-Cayley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem) theorem it would follow that $m_{A}(t) \mid t^{n}-1$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}-\{0\}$

We can notice that $t^{n}-1 = \prod_\limits{d \mid n} \phi_{d}(t)$

([Proving that cyclotomic polynomials have integer coefficients](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1639645/proving-that-cyclotomic-polynomials-have-integer-coefficients))

Where $\phi_{d}(t)$ are the $d-th$ cyclotomic polynomial, and this factorization lie in $\mathbb{Z}[t]$.

Since we noticed that $P_{A}(t)$ is irreducibile over $\mathbb{Q}[t]$ which is (UFD),

If $P_{A}(t)$ would divide $t^{n}-1$ it would coincide with one of the irreducible factors of $t^{n}-1$, but those lie in $\mathbb{Z}[t]$, while $P_{A}(t)$ don't.

> Edit : If orb($e_{1}$) would be finite, even the orbit of $x=Ae_{1}$ would be finite.
>
> But $e_{1},x$ are linearly independent and we have shown that $A^{n}e_{1} = e_{1}$ and $A^{m}x=x$ for some $m,n$. It would follow that $A^{nm} = I_{d}$
>
> Ps : If you're interested in finding the powers of $A$, a way to start could be noticing that the Jordan form of $A$ is indeed, a rotation, which powers are relatively easily computable.
> (Questions of this kind or similar have been answered on MSE [Powers of Rotation matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2460240/powers-of-rotation-matrix))

Comment: $A$ can have infinite order, but $e_1$ finite orbit...

Comment: @manifold I see, I din't really specified the conclusion. I edited the answer,now should work.

Comment: It is interesting to note 2 things. The first one is that your proof works for every matrix of the form $\left(\begin{matrix}0&1\\-1& \frac{1}{n} \end{matrix}\right)$ with $n\in \mathbb Z-\{0\}$. The second one is that you also show that every vector has an infinite orbit under the action of this type of matrices